# One view controller per NSTabViewItem in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nstabview

I am writing an application for mac OSX in swift and I would like to separate the code clearly so I am looking for a way to have a view controller for each NSTabViewItem in a NSTabView without use the Tab View Controller. Is it possible ?

Comment: Storyboard or xibs?

Comment: Storyboard, I don't know what's  "xibs". I am a beginner with xcode and swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. 
It’s possible to do that with a “Container view”. I put a Container View in a view. I created a new view controller. Finally, I linked both with Ctrl-Drag from container view to the new view controller and selected "embed".
More information in this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/153844/macos-view-controllers-tutorial)